# Batch Extract Folder of *.iso

Tags: windows, batch, iso-image

I'm trying to take a folder full of disc images (ISO) and create a subfolder for each ISO (using the ISO's name), mount the ISO, and copy all of the content into that folder. I need it to loop so it extracts all of the ISOs in the folder. So far I have

```
@echo off

for %%X in (*.iso) do if not exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Deskstop\ISO Extractions\%%~nX" (
      echo creating directory "C:\Users\Administrator\Deskstop\ISO Extractions\%%~nX"
      mkdir "C:\Users\Administrator\Deskstop\ISO Extractions\%%~nX"
    ) else (
      echo directory "C:\Users\Administrator\Deskstop\ISO Extractions\%%~nX" already exists
    )
```

I'm about as new as it gets so I'm not sure how to mount the drive and use xcopy to get in into the appropriate folder. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Really need mount to add all files from ISO to another folder with the same name? Also, need to do this with xcopy? Why not use your bat with winrar to extract these file to respective target folder?

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll look into using winrar for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got what I needed to do with 7zip. Here is the code.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in ( `dir /b /s *.iso` ) do 7z x "%%f" -o"%%~pf%%~nf"
```

This requires the 7z file in the directory of the *.iso files. It creates a folder with the ISO name and extracts each ISO to that folder.

Thanks @It Wasn't Me for pointing out that I didn't need to mount the ISOs if I used an unzipping program.

Comment: You can do this in Powershell without relying on 3rd party software